# How do I read file path from a text file with multiple paths to another text files and copy their data into a single text file with a condition

Tags: python, text, path, output, read-write

Lets take a example of a text file called output.txt with multiple paths to different text file. How do I read them all and copy their data into a single text file with a condition like if the text file has n number of characters and n number of words or any special characters and by n I mean taking input from the user directly of how many words and characters.

```
import os
import glob
import sys
import linecache
def output():

    extensions=('.txt', '.csv')
    exclude=set(['AppData', 'System32', 'Program Files', '.vscode', 'Videos', 'Games', 'Program Files (x86)'])
    # traverse whole directory
    sys.stdout = open("output.txt", "a")
    for dname, dirs, files in os.walk('C:'):
        dirs[:]=[d for d in dirs if d not in exclude]
        for fname in files:
            if (fname.lower().endswith(extensions)):
                fpath3=os.path.join(dname, fname)
                print(fpath3)

    sys.stdout.close()

    sys.stdout = open("output.txt", "a")
    for dname1, dirs1, files1 in os.walk('D:'):
        dirs1[:]=[d for d in dirs1 if d not in exclude]
        for fname1 in files1:
            if (fname1.lower().endswith(extensions)):
                fpath4=os.path.join(dname1, fname1)
                print(fpath4)

    sys.stdout.close()

    sys.stdout = open("output.txt", "a")
    for dname2, dirs2, files2 in os.walk('E:'):
        dirs2[:]=[d for d in dirs2 if d not in exclude]
        for fname2 in files2:
            if (fname2.lower().endswith(extensions)):
                fpath5=os.path.join(dname2, fname2)
                print(fpath5)
sys.stdout.close()
output()
```

```
#this text file has many paths to text files
output.txt

C:Documents\Mods\test1.txt
C:Documents\Logs\test2.txt
C:Documents\Docs\test3.txt

#and so on
```

Expecting the script to read multiple text files from a text file with paths and taking input from the users for how many characters he wants to find in the text file (if it has more than the characters specified it will not copy it onto the output file) and compile all the data into one output file

Comment: I think I missed the section where you showed your code so far ??

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Which part specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: I don't have trouble with it, I am new to python and don't know much about it, I need help in creating a logic to read a text file with multiple paths and copy the content and compile it into one file @wwii

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem